# How do I do substitution with a call to format?

Tags: clojure

I have a function

```
(defn f-test [c-width] (format "%-(c-width)s" "boogey"))
```

This is what happens when I try to evaluate it

```
(f-test 10)

FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException Conversion = c, Flags = (  java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failMismatch (Formatter.java:4041)
```

But this is what I am trying to do

```
(format "%-10s" "boogey")

"boogey    "
```

how can I substitute in c-width inside the format call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(defn f-test 
  [c-width] 
  (format (str "%-" c-width "s") "boogey"))
```